# Data seeding is not working with Entity Framework in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I have added these two files in Data folder in application folder.

After running the `update-database` command, no changes are found in the database. Please guide if I have missed something for seeding.

Point to be noted: CRUD operation using application is working fine. So there is no other issue in controller or model.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a good idea to provide code not images, so that we can find the problem quickly .

Comment: Set a breakpoint at   `if(context.Staffs.Any())` to see it will excute `return`or not .

Comment: Did you run the command `add-migration` ?

Comment: @klekmek yes, after run the migration, I update the DB by update-database

Comment: Why don't you try to seed using the recommended way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Comment: @klekmek I tried this official recommendation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0#initialize-db-with-test-data

Comment: @Billu 

Seeding this way isn't triggered by migrations you'll need to specifically call your DB initializer method.

Can you post a snapshot of your program.cs - the documentation you refer to also requires you to have CreateDbIfNotExists(host);